# JavaScript, get url body in a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, url, variables

I know it is an easy one, sorry for asking, but I’m going mad and I cannot get it. Must be the fundamentals, I’ve got them all mix up :((

I have this url:

https://www.myweb.sub.com/~user/folder/file.php?param=Value

I need to get:

https://www.myweb.sub.com/~user/folder/

in a variable.

Please help to achieve it.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) and [`lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) methods:

```
var url = "https://www.myweb.sub.com/~user/folder/file.php?param=Value"; 
var segment = url.slice(0, url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

If your current URL is actually `https://www.myweb.sub.com/~user/folder/file.php?param=Value`, operate on `window.location.href` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt, you saved me from going nuts :))

Answer (score 1):

So we don't chew it all up for you, here's a link that should set you on the right path:

find the last index of a character with this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp

get the substring of a string with this:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Tell us if you still need help after that.

Answer (score 0):

use this :-

```
var str="https://www.myweb.sub.com/~user/folder/file.php?param=Value";
var n=str.substring(0,str.indexOf("file"));
```